# Find where a python function is defined

Tags: python, function, class, visual-studio-code

I am trying to improve a set of python files written by a co-worker. There are many scripts and each script calls all the functions and classes from other files

```
from file1.py import *
from file2.py import *
...
```

And at times it gets complicated to figured out where the functions are defined. Is there a short way to find the location of functions? And also their definitions? Also, if possible, where a variable is being used? I use VSCode.

Comment: This is one reason `from ... import *` is frowned upon. As you figure out, for example, that `foo` comes from `file1`, do one of two things: 1) add `from file1 import foo`, or 2) add `import file1` and use `file1.foo`. Once you are sure you have accounted for everything from `file1`, get rid of `from file1 import *` altogether.

Comment: You've probably tried this already, but does right-clicking on an identifier name and selecting "Go to Definition" not work?

Comment: You don't get a `ModuleNotFoundError` for `file1.py`? I'm not sure that's the proper syntax there... I would have used `import file1 as f1`.  But I digress.  VSCode should have "Go to definition" and "Go to references" in the context menu when you right click on the functions.

Comment: @chepner For a language that promotes "Explicit is better than implicit", I'm honestly surprised at the amount of people I see that uses star imports, especially some in widely used packages.

Comment: I tried go to definition. Did not get errors nor a response. Overall, there's a lot I have to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've been in this exact scenario, and my process was as follows:

Scenario where **file2.py** includes statements like `from file1 import *`.

> 1. In **file1.py**, I would copy all the import statements, and paste them in **file2.py**
> 2. I would copy all the top-level function/class names, and set them up as comma-delimited, and replace the `*` in **file2.py**: `from file1 import file1_method1, file1_method2, file1_class1`.
>      I don't have VS Code, but I'm sure there's a way to look at the File Structure view and copy the list and reformat it into the import statement.
> 3. Repeat steps 1-2 for every `from x import *`, it's best to start from core files, and then work your way out to dependent files (reduce work for nested `import *` statements)
> 4. Search **file2.py** for any [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) statements which may reference other modules, and manually import those. If no [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), then skip.
> 5. Optional: Sort the import statements (yay OCD!)
> 6. Once this is done, I let the linter work, and remove all unused references (including duplicate imports) except those needed by `eval`, perhaps add comment for linter to ignore these.
> 7. Run your code, and pray you didn't make mistakes (nothing to worry if you didn't!)
> 8. Repeat 1-7 for every file in your application!
> 9. ???
> 10. Profit!

This has been tough, but really has been worth it after all that work to trace what is being used and where in each file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know where a particular function comes from, I think you can find the module using the `__module__` property. You could use:

```
print(myFunction.__module__)
```

To get the file it has been imported from. You can then use:

```
print(myModule.__file__)
```

To work out the path to the file the module is from.